# How to test react components embedded in angular application?

Tags: reactjs, angular, unit-testing

I use components written in React in my Angular 10 project. The page creates an Angular component (tsx file), then when the view is initialized I use ReactDom.render to display a React component using ViewChild.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a complete tutorial on how to create tests for React components and set up the environment accordingly. Can you suggest me to such an article or provide instructions on how to configure it correctly?

The desired solution is to leave the scripts and run tests for angular components unchanged and run the tests, e.g. using react-testing-library with a separate command (only for React components)